# How can I get the ID of the motherboard from Air application?

Tags: air, motherboard

What are some ways to get the ID of the motherboard using Air application?

Answer (score 1):

Native helper application, no other way around. There is no mention of motherboards/bios version/other deep system stuff in AIR docs.

Comment: is there no API that help us with AIR for getting ID ?